# lvcreate hangs on snapshot creation

Tags: lvm

on a Debian testing lvcreate hangs on snapshot creation since some weeks:

[image: Image I took with the smartphone because the PC was totally stuck]

A that point I have to hardware reset the machine. After reboot the log file is empty and syslog shows nothing. On another similar machine I do not have this problem. Any idea?

Update: even giving a `shutdown -r +3` before `lvcreate` it is ignored and it doesn't make the system reboot after a "timeout" of 3 minutes.

With -d option of `lvcreate` I found this into `syslog`:

```
Jun 26 09:08:31 mysystem kernel: [600967.998857] debugfs: Directory 'dm-1' with parent 'block' already present!
```

... but I don't know what it means. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I tried deleting old config files in `/etc/udev/rules.d` as suggested in other posts, but without success. This is what I get if I run the command with `strace` (only the last part, because *"Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 199034."*):

```bash
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/vg00/backup", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/vg00/backup", O_RDWR|O_DIRECT|O_NOATIME) = 3
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x5591c0060056, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x5591c0060056, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[INT KILL TERM STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(3, BLKZEROOUT, [0, 4096])         = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, ~[INT KILL TERM STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, NULL, 8) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mapper/control", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xa, 0xec), ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mapper/control", O_RDWR) = 3
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG}) = 0
getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0)            = 20
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -18)       = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_DEPS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=328, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "}\366", 2)                     = 2
semget(0xd4df67d, 1, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0600) = 5
semctl(5, 0, SETVAL, 0x7ffd00000001)    = 0
semctl(5, 0, GETVAL, NULL)              = 1
close(4)                                = 0
semtimedop(5, [{0, 1, 0}], 1, NULL)     = 0
semctl(5, 0, GETVAL, NULL)              = 2
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_REMOVE, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), event_nr=6354557, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG|DM_UEVENT_GENERATED_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, 0)         = 0
semget(0xd4df67d, 1, 000)               = 5
semctl(5, 0, GETVAL, NULL)              = 1
semtimedop(5, [{0, -1, IPC_NOWAIT}], 1, NULL) = 0
semtimedop(5, [{0, 0, 0}], 1, NULL)     = 0
semctl(5, 0, IPC_RMID, NULL)            = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\364\362\6'c3\364\331F\236M\262\245\20\316\252\203\375\353\345\35\341\222\237Z\224\374\241^\342\310\252", 32) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x5591c0060056, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x5591c0060056, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[INT KILL TERM STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lvm/archive", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
access("/etc/lvm/archive", R_OK|W_OK|X_OK) = 0
getpid()                                = 3276
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="xxx", ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_xxx_3276_1560677372", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_APPEND, 0666) = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETLK, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8401 (flags O_WRONLY|O_APPEND|O_LARGEFILE)
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=0, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
write(3, "# Generated by LVM2 version 2.03"..., 1732) = 1732
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lvm/archive", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
getdents64(3, 0x5591c1b7d5f0 /* 13 entries */, 32768) = 576
getdents64(3, 0x5591c1b7d5f0 /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
link("/etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_xxx_3276_1560677372", "/etc/lvm/archive/vg00_03502-2000208694.vg") = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_xxx_3276_1560677372", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=1732, ...}, 0) = 0
unlink("/etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_xxx_3276_1560677372") = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/lvm/archive/vg00_03492-643924088.vg", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=1319, ...}, 0) = 0
unlink("/etc/lvm/archive/vg00_03492-643924088.vg") = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, ~[INT KILL TERM STOP RTMIN RT_1], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, ~[KILL STOP RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fc224f36920}, NULL, 8) = 0
io_submit(0x7fc22540d000, 1, [{aio_data=0, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PWRITE, aio_fildes=5, aio_buf="vg00 {\nid = \"oEBEh0-2QYO-v855-m9"..., aio_nbytes=131072, aio_offset=786432}]) = 1
io_getevents(0x7fc22540d000, 1, 64, [{data=0, obj=0x5591c13566e8, res=131072, res2=0}], NULL) = 1
io_submit(0x7fc22540d000, 1, [{aio_data=0, aio_lio_opcode=IOCB_CMD_PWRITE, aio_fildes=5, aio_buf="\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., aio_nbytes=4608, aio_offset=0}]) = 1
io_getevents(0x7fc22540d000, 1, 64, [{data=0, obj=0x5591c13566e8, res=4608, res2=0}], NULL) = 1
getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0)            = 20
setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -18)       = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mapper/control", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(0xa, 0xec), ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/mapper/control", O_RDWR) = 3
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_DEPS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=328, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/md1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x9, 0x1), ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/md1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x9, 0x1), ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/md1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x9, 0x1), ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/md1", {st_mode=S_IFBLK|0660, st_rdev=makedev(0x9, 0x1), ...}, 0) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_CREATE, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, name="vg00-lv00-real", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-lv00-real", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-lv00-real", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-lv00-real", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=361, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_CREATE, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, name="vg00-backup-cow", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x2), name="vg00-backup-cow", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x2), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x2), name="vg00-backup-cow", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x2), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x2), name="vg00-backup-cow", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "\2258", 2)                     = 2
semget(0xd4d3895, 1, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0600) = 6
semctl(6, 0, SETVAL, 0x7ffd00000001)    = 0
semctl(6, 0, GETVAL, NULL)              = 1
close(4)                                = 0
semtimedop(6, [{0, 1, 0}], 1, NULL)     = 0
semctl(6, 0, GETVAL, NULL)              = 2
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_SUSPEND, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x2), event_nr=8272021, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x2), name="vg00-backup-cow", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q-cow", target_count=1, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG|DM_UEVENT_GENERATED_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_CREATE, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x3), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x3), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x3), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_STATUS_TABLE_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_LOAD, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x3), target_count=1, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG, ...} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x3), name="vg00-backup", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6pTLvreC6XNmvIU8hz3yafUjLb1wwhG6q", target_count=0, open_count=0, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(0x5591c23a2000)                     = 0x5591c23a2000
brk(0x5591c258a000)                     = 0x5591c258a000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2996, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(4, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2996
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/it_IT.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/it_IT.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/it_IT/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/it.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/it.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (File o directory non esistente)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=123142, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 123142, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7fc2253ee000
close(4)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 4
newfstatat(4, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=27002, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 27002, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 4, 0) = 0x7fc224add000
close(4)                                = 0
futex(0x7fc2250cd9bc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/self/maps", O_RDONLY) = 4
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "5591bfedc000-5591bff12000 r--p 0"..., 8192) = 3983
read(4, "7fc224c8a000-7fc224c9e000 r--p 0"..., 4209) = 4063
read(4, "7fc224e70000-7fc224e7b000 r--p 0"..., 146) = 146
lseek(4, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(4, "5591bfedc000-5591bff12000 r--p 0"..., 16384) = 3983
read(4, "7fc224c8a000-7fc224c9e000 r--p 0"..., 12401) = 4063
read(4, "7fc224e70000-7fc224e7b000 r--p 0"..., 8338) = 4069
read(4, "7fc225278000-7fc225279000 r--p 0"..., 4269) = 3974
read(4, "", 295)                        = 0
mlock(0x5591bfedc000, 221184)           = 0
mlock(0x5591bff12000, 1900544)          = 0
mlock(0x5591c00e2000, 741376)           = 0
mlock(0x5591c0197000, 40960)            = 0
mlock(0x5591c01a1000, 245760)           = 0
mlock(0x5591c01dd000, 2752512)          = 0
mlock(0x5591c1315000, 19353600)         = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ae4000, 28672)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224b14000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224b16000, 28672)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224b1d000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224b1f000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224b20000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224be6000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224be8000, 20480)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224bed000, 643072)           = 0
mlock(0x7fc224c8a000, 81920)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224c9f000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ca0000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e0f000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e1b000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e1d000, 16384)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e21000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e23000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e24000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e25000, 16384)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e29000, 49152)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e35000, 12288)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e39000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e3a000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e3b000, 12288)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e70000, 45056)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224e7b000, 299008)           = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ec4000, 81920)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ed8000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ed9000, 12288)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224edc000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224edd000, 24576)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ee3000, 61440)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ef2000, 24576)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ef8000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224ef9000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc224efa000, 16384)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc224efe000, 139264)           = 0
mlock(0x7fc224f20000, 1409024)          = 0
mlock(0x7fc225078000, 327680)           = 0
mlock(0x7fc2250c8000, 16384)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc2250cc000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc2250ce000, 36864)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc2250d7000, 53248)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc2250e4000, 630784)           = 0
mlock(0x7fc22517e000, 630784)           = 0
mlock(0x7fc225219000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc22521a000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc225245000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc225274000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253a4000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253da000, 16384)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253de000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253e0000, 16384)            = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253e4000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253e5000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253e6000, 4096)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc2253e7000, 8192)             = 0
mlock(0x7fc22540d000, 20480)            = 0
mlock(0x7ffdd1a6c000, 135168)           = 0
mlock(0x7ffdd1b03000, 16384)            = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_DEPS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=328, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-lv00-real", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", target_count=0, open_count=2, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_TABLE_DEPS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=16384, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, data_start=312, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0x1), name="vg00-lv00-real", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-real", target_count=0, open_count=2, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=2048, uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G-cow", flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG}) = -1 ENXIO (Device o indirizzo non esistente)
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_STATUS, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG} => {version=4.46.0, data_size=305, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), name="vg00-lv00", uuid="LVM-oEBEh02QYOv855m94eKGWHmzbiJFbKa6KQtaXBEl7YvprIeIXw8otru9FEU49K0G", target_count=1, open_count=1, event_nr=0, flags=DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_ACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_INACTIVE_PRESENT_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}) = 0
ioctl(3, DM_DEV_SUSPEND, {version=4.0.0, data_size=2048, dev=makedev(0xfd, 0), flags=DM_SUSPEND_FLAG|DM_EXISTS_FLAG|DM_PERSISTENT_DEV_FLAG|DM_SKIP_BDGET_FLAG}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add text, not image